# How to create a .bashrc file when the user has a remote directory

Tags: bash, rubygems, pam

I am trying to configure a custom prompt for RHEL 8 users. It works very nice when the users have local home directories.

However, I'm mounting home directories via pam_mount (nfs4). When ssh'ing to the machine, the prompt I made displays fine. But when opening a terminal in Gnome, the bash is the default `bash4.4$`.

I've tried to setup these on /etc/profile, adding a file to /etc/profile.d, and also to /etc/bashrc, to no avail.

EDIT: Just to make things clear: I do understand that ssh'ing x opening a terminal will have prompts defined on different places. My issue here is that I got to define a prompt that works when I open a terminal on Gnome (and when ssh'ing the machine), but that prompt doesn't show up as defined when the home directory is mounted from a remote server (although it still works when ssh'ing the machine).

Any idea on how to do it?

Best,

Francis

Comment: bash doesn't use `/etc/bashrc`, but `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. Same results.